# Additional To is showing only coworkers email

Tags: email2case

I have setup email to case and case is creating fine. Issue with forward or reply on the mail. I can not add email address in Addition To box. When I clicked on lookup it shows only coworkers emails.

How can I add other emails.

Comment: Did you set an account for the case? If an account is selected, you'll have an option for "Contacts: <<Account Name>>" that you can also email to.

Comment: How can I set an account for the case. I would appreciate if you guide me.

Comment: Use the Account field on the Case to specify the Account, or use the Contact field to specify a Contact, which will also populate the Account with the Contact's Account. You may need to add those fields to your Case Page Layout, and/or set the Field Level Security to Editable for those two fields.